# Error "Undefined" al eliminar elementos duplicados

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un `modal` con elementos que se repiten y lo que hago es eliminar aquellos repetidos. Me funciona pero me bota un error en la consola que no quiero que aparezca:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`.

Me gustaría saber el por qué del error y cómo solucionarlo.

```js
function delete_elements() {
  if ($(".modal-body").length) {
    $(".modal-body").find(".row")[1].remove();
    $(".modal-body").find(".modal-footer")[1].remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <!-- ko if: es_vacio(viewModel.mantenimiento.COD_US())-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input inputmodal" data-bind="value: mantenimiento.CODI_EMPL_PER_TXT, event: { change : function(){validatePersonal();}}" id="lista_empleado" placeholder="Ingrese datos del Personal" />
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-bind="value: mantenimiento.CODI_EMPL_PER_TXT()" />
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal">Personal:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal" for="txtDescAlm">Email:</label>
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="txtDescAlm" data-bind="value: mantenimiento.US_EMAIL" placeholder="Ingrese Email del Personal" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal" for="sede">Sede:</label>
        <select class="mdl-textfield__input" data-bind="options: listaSedes, optionsText: 'DESC_SEDE_SED', optionsValue: 'CODI_SEDE_SED', value: viewModel.mantenimiento.SEDE , event: { change : function(){ buscar_dependencias(viewModel.mantenimiento.SEDE(),true); } }">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal">Dependencia:</label>
        <select class="mdl-textfield__input" data-bind="options: listaDependencias, optionsText: 'DESC_DEPE_TDE', optionsValue: 'CODI_DEPE_TDE', value: viewModel.mantenimiento.CODI_DEPE_TDE">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal">Tipo de Usuario:</label>
        <select class="mdl-textfield__input" data-bind="options: listaTipoUsuario, optionsText: 'DESCRIPCION', optionsValue: 'PARCOD', value: viewModel.mantenimiento.TIPO_US, event: {change : function(){ delete_elements(); } }"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Password" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal" for="txtPassword">Contraseña:</label>
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="txtPassword" data-bind="value: mantenimiento.US_PASS" autofocus placeholder="Ingrese Contraseña del Usuario" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PasswordConfirm" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-focused has-placeholder">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label labelmodal" for="txtPasswordConfirm">Confirmar Contraseña:</label>
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="txtPasswordConfirm" data-bind="value: mantenimiento.US_PASS_CONFIRM" autofocus placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="validate_password()">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, por que no utilizas la función filter de ES6 para quitar los repetidos y te evitas de usar JQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si ese es todo tu código `HTML`, pero si lo es, es lógico que te esté lanzando ese error, te explico lo que estás haciendo paso por paso:

```
$(".modal-body");
```

Lo anterior es un elemento `jQuery` que contendrá todos los elementos que tengan la clase `modal-body`.

```
$(".modal-body").find(".row");
```

Lo anterior sigue siendo un elemento `jQuery` que seleccionará todos los elementos que tengan la clase `modal-body` y después buscará dentro de ellos a elementos con la clase `row`.

```
$(".modal-body").find(".row")[1];
```

Lo anterior ya deja de ser un elemento `jQuery`, estás accediendo directamente al segundo nodo `HTML` dentro de la selección `jQuery` (de existir, si no hay más de un nodo no existirá). Por lo tanto, lo anterior te devolverá un nodo `HTML` o `undefined` dependiendo de la cantidad de nodos y al índice que estés intentando acceder.

Observa el siguiente snippet:

```js
var $rows = $(".modal-body").find('.row');

console.log( '$rows[0] =>', $rows[0] );
console.log( '$rows[1] =>', $rows[1] );
console.log( '$rows[2] =>', $rows[2] );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">0</div>
  <div class="row">1</div>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver, al existir solo dos elementos con la clase `row` dentro de `modal-body`, `$rows[0]` es el primer elemento, `$rows[1]` es el segundo, pero `$rows[2]` es `undefined` porque no existe un tercer elemento dentro de la selección.

En tu código `HTML` solo hay un elemento con la clase `row` y un elemento con la clase `modal-footer`. Intentar hacer una selección `jQuery` de esos elementos e intentar borrar el segundo elemento (el cual no existe), es como intentar el siguiente código:

```
var row = undefined;
row.remove();
```

El anterior código te lanzará tu mismo error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Por lo tanto, si deseas borrar el segundo elemento (si existe), pero si no existe que no te lance error, lo mejor es que chequees primero si existe:

```
var $rows = $(".modal-body").find(".row");

if ($rows[1]) {
    $rows[1].remove();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, era la validación que estaba mal, lo arreglé como me indicaste y funciono :D

Comment: De nada, me alegro que lo hayas solucionado.